# Nested view performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, view

I have this SQL-query:

```
SELECT Start,
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'WP'),0) AS Werkplaats_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'WP'),0) AS Werkplaats_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'MAG'),0) AS Magazijn_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'MAG'),0) AS Magazijn_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SERV'),0) AS Service_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SERV'),0) AS Service_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'CNC'),0) AS Draaibank_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'CNC'),0) AS Draaibank_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SECL'),0) AS Bougiekabels_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SECL'),0) AS Bougiekabels_tijd 
FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b1
GROUP BY Start
```

I could explain what my query does, but I don't think that would be relevant as the query already works fine. My only problem is the processing time; I have to wait 20-25 seconds for my result and I think that's a bit to long.

What SQL Server seems to do (I think), is `SELECT` my values 11 times from view `[pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW` (10 times for each of my subquery's and 1 time for my normal query). That's a heavy task because `SELECT * FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW` has a processing time from about 2 seconds. `SELECT` is not neccessary, it should be enough to refer it one time and use the result in each of the subquery's. I tested if my performance-issue is really because of the subquery, and it is: when I reduce my query to just 2 instead of 10 subquery's, the processing time is just 6-7 seconds.

Just for information, here is a part of the result of `[pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW`:

```
    Start       Afdeling    Orders  Tijd
    2013-05-14  SERV        3       0
    2013-05-14  WP          17      0
    2013-05-15  MAG         1       0
    2013-05-15  SERV        3       0
    2013-05-15  WP          14      0
    2013-05-16  CNC         1       0
    2013-05-16  MAG         9       0
    2013-05-16  SERV        3       0
    2013-05-16  WP          22      0
    2013-05-17  MAG         19      0
    2013-05-17  WP          8       0
    2013-05-20  MAG         11      0
```

My explicit question is: Is it possible to `SELECT` the results of `[pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW` only one time and use the result of this in every subquery (instead of trigger this `SELECT` query 10 times again), or, if not possible, is there any other way to reduce the processing time for my query?

Comment: have you considered an index?

Comment: You need to look at `Pivot`. You can rewrite this to do one `SELECT` example with one column is `SELECT Start,ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Orders END ),0) AS Werkplaats_ord FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW GROUP BY Start`. Follow the pattern for the remaining columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This query should solve your problem (including if you can have negative Orders/Time values).

```
SELECT Start,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Orders END),0) AS Werkplaats_ord,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Tijd END),0) AS Werkplaats_tijd, 
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'MAG' THEN Orders END),0) AS Magazijn_ord,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'MAG' THEN Tijd END),0) AS Magazijn_tijd, 
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SERV' THEN Orders END),0) AS Service_ord,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SERV' THEN Tijd END),0) AS Service_tijd, 
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'CNC' THEN Orders END),0) AS Draaibank_ord,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'CNC' THEN Tijd END),0) AS Draaibank_tijd, 
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SECL' THEN Orders END),0) AS Bougiekabels_ord,
    ISNULL(MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SECL' THEN Tijd END),0) AS Bougiekabels_tijd 
FROM [pp].dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b1
GROUP BY Start
```

Comment: I don't understand the comment about negative Orders/Time values. Why do you think they would need special handling?

Comment: Because if you don't have any negative value, you could write this query in a lighter manner. Exemple : MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) AS Werkplaats_ord,

Comment: @Serge That would not have the same semantics as the original if no matching row existed. It would return `NULL` rather than `0`

Comment: So, my answer is not the one you validate, you prefer the 22 seconds answer of Devart (who just edited his answer to add my query to his answer).

Comment: @Martin you're wrong. For each row that exist there will be a value for each column. As for rows that don't even exist... what paradox would it be if I managed to output them?!

Comment: @Serge - Yes you're right. I never use an `ELSE` clause when Pivoting and missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          Orders
        , Tijd
        , Afdeling
        , Start 
    FROM dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW    
)
SELECT Start,
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'WP'),0) AS Werkplaats_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'WP'),0) AS Werkplaats_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'MAG'),0) AS Magazijn_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'MAG'),0) AS Magazijn_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SERV'),0) AS Service_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SERV'),0) AS Service_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'CNC'),0) AS Draaibank_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'CNC'),0) AS Draaibank_tijd, 
    ISNULL((SELECT Orders FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SECL'),0) AS Bougiekabels_ord,
    ISNULL((SELECT Tijd FROM cte b2 WHERE b2.Start=b1.Start AND Afdeling = 'SECL'),0) AS Bougiekabels_tijd 
FROM cte b1
GROUP BY Start
```

Or try this -

```
SELECT 
    Start,
    Werkplaats_ord = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) ,
    Werkplaats_tijd = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'WP' THEN Tijd ELSE 0 END) , 
    Magazijn_ord = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'MAG' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) ,
    Magazijn_tijd = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'MAG' THEN Tijd ELSE 0 END) , 
    Service_ord = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SERV' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) ,
    Service_tijd = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SERV' THEN Tijd ELSE 0 END) , 
    Draaibank_ord = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'CNC' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) ,
    Draaibank_tijd = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'CNC' THEN Tijd ELSE 0 END) , 
    Bougiekabels_ord = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SECL' THEN Orders ELSE 0 END) ,
    Bougiekabels_tijd = MIN(CASE WHEN Afdeling = 'SECL' THEN Tijd ELSE 0 END)  
FROM dbo.VW_BEZETTING_RAW b1
GROUP BY Start
```

Comment: Feel free to copy other answers and claim them as your own. [pp]

Comment: first solution still 22 seconds, your second only 2! great!

Comment: @Serge, When I finished my answer - you already answered. And please note I "not just edit" you answer. So the question's author may decide to choose your answer though.

Comment: @Devart, I saw you edit your post when you just had submited the first part. I didn't downvoted your answer or anything though because I don't hold a grudge over this trivial matter.

Comment: @Serge, I glad to heart it.